# Redirect from one site to another

Tags: opencart

I have 2 website: Site A and Site B. When a customer purchases something on Site A, I want them to be redirected to Site B for checkout. Then, to be redirected back to Site A upon a completed payment.

let me know how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Site A** has its own database with user's info, shipment info, etc.
If Site B processes only the payment and the it redirects to Site A, you will need to write (or clone and modify) one of the payment methods already integrated on Opencart.
I Advise you to clone one of the credit card payment methods because **they post checkout data to the payment gateway** (in your case **Site B**) and when the payment is complete, Site B will redirect to Site A. 
If you follow this solution, you only have to change the POST variables of the original payment gateway with your own POST variables (firstname, lastname, order ID, amount, etc.)
**This way all the customer info and order info will be stored only on Site A** (Site B could still store some info, like the order id and payment status but to avoid redundancy it would be better to keep all the info on one site only).

If your question is "**How to complete the full checkout process on Site B when user buys a list of product on Site A**" Then things are more complex and probably not feasible.

Your question doesn't specify it but I suppose both the sites are Opencart stores.
In that case the easiest way would be using a **multistore**, because Site A and Site B would share the same database, thus same customers and same orders.

If Site A and Site B don't belong to the same multistore, things start to become a mess, I will describe you only a small part of the problems you will encounter:

In order to checkout on Site B, the list of products must be posted from Site A to Site B, together with the customer id (or customer email), that is supposed to be present and itentical on both the sites for registered users. For non registered users, if user registers on Site A, the same registration must be cloned on Site B. Also the catalog of the two sites must be the same on both the sites (and also product quantities must match, if a product on Site B is out of stock while is still in stock on Site A, when you redirect a user from A to B, Site B would redirect you back to the cart page, with the message "product not available").